# Laravel 5.4: call a route function from controller with parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I want to call a route function from my controller with some parameters.

This is my Controller

```
public function myFunction($id, $name)
{
    $id = 1;
    $name = 'john';

    return redirect()->route('details/' . $id . '/' . $name);
}
```

This is my route

```
Route::get('details/{id}/{name}',['uses' =>'My_controller@myFunction']);
```

This is the error I get when I run the script.

```
InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 304:

Route [details/1/john] not defined.
```

Please Help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`route()` helper requires you to pass route name and parameters:

```
function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
{
    return app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
}
```

So you need to give your route a name:

```
Route::get('details/{id}/{name}',['uses' =>'My_controller@myFunction'])->name('details');
```

..and then you can pass parameters in an array:

```
return redirect()->route('details', array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: deleting my answer ,you beat me by few seconds :)